# how to install ocr engine (tesseract) and pyteeser for python2.7 in windows7

Tags: windows, python-2.7, ocr

Can you please help me to install tesseract and pyteeser for Python2.7 on Windows 7?

A download link and detailed steps how to install these packages would be preferred.

I tried using `easy_install` but it threw an error

I installed pyteeser, also changed `import Image` to `from PIL import image` in pyteeser.py file.

But now i am getting this error

> File
>   "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 699, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 74, in execfile
>       exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
>
> File "C:/Users/Duggentious/Documents/Python Scripts/print
>   inspection/ocrstore.py", line 15, in 
>       text = image_to_string(im)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pytesser.py", line 31, in
>   image_to_string
>       call_tesseract(scratch_image_name, scratch_text_name_root)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pytesser.py", line 21, in
>   call_tesseract
>       proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in **init**
>       errread, errwrite)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo)
>
> WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified``

Answer (score 0):

Try my guide - it may work for you.

Steps for getting pytesseract working on windows.

1. Install Anaconda 2 or Anaconda 3 from https://www.continuum.io/downloads
2. Install tesseract for windows from http://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/tesseract-ocr-setup-4.00.00dev.exe
3. Add the tesseract directory to windows as a PATH environment variable.
4. Install pytesseract e.g. pip install pytesseract
   and..

   ```
   import pytesseract
   from PIL import Image
   image = Image.open('example_02.png')
   code = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
   print code
   ```

voila.